# Is there a better design for 'as needed' web interface with flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a python program which is doing millions of comparisons across records.  Occasionally a comparison fails and I need to have a user (me) step and update a record.  Today I do this by calling a function which:

1. creates a flask 'app'
2. creates and populates a wtform form to collect the necessary information
3. instantiates the flask app (e.g. app.run() and webbrowser.open() call to pull up the form)
4. I update the data in the form, when the form is submitted, the handler puts the updated data into a variable and then shuts down the flask app returning the 
   data to the caller

This seems kludgy.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this recognizing that this is not a typical client-driven web application?

The minimal problem is how best to programmatically launch an 'as needed' web-based UI which presents a form, and then return back the submitted data to the caller.

My method works, but seems a poor design to meet the goal.

Comment: I would... not use a Flask app for this. I'd just use the command line. You could even use the `cmd` module if you want something more fancy than just straight up `input`-ness

Comment: I'm using a web form as that lends itself well to the data (images laid out in a table format with options that need to be turned on/off)

Answer (score 0):

As I have not yet found a better way - in case someone else has a similar need, here is how I'm meeting the goal:

...

```
if somedata_needs_review:
    review_status = user_review(somedata)
    update_data(review_status)
```

...

```
def user_review(data_to_review):
    """ Present web form to user and receive their input """

    returnstruct = {}
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def show_review_form():
        form = create_review_form(data_to_review)
        return render_template('reviewtemplate.tpl', form=form)

    # TODO - I currently split the handling into a different route because
    # when using the same route previously Safari would warn of resubmitting data.
    # This has the slightly unfortunate effect of creating multiple tabs.

    @app.route('/process_compare', methods=['POST'])
    def process_review_form():
        # this form object will be populated with the submitted information
        form = create_review_form(request.form, matchrecord=matchrecord)

        # handle submitted updates however necessary 
        returnstruct['matched'] = form.process_changes.data

        shutdown_flask_server()
        return "Changes submitted, you can close this tab"

    webbrowser.open('http://localhost:5000/', autoraise=True)
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)

    # The following will execute after the app is shutdown.
    print('Finished manual review, returning {}'.format(returnstruct))
    return(returnstruct)

def shutdown_flask_server():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
```